# Why does the window.localStorage convert its value to a string?

Tags: javascript, browser

As many of you probably know you can assign a number of function or object to `window.localStorage` and the data will automatically be converted to a string. I've see several answers that help to get around this, but my question is why is localStorage built like this? Is it a security issue? I'm wonder what the purpose/design/philosophy behind this is.

Comment: simply, it's how [it is spec'd](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage) `Keys are strings. Any string (including the empty string) is a valid key. Values are similarly strings.`

Comment: @JaromandaX Interestingly at least one [Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091222/) states _"Each Storage object provides access to a list of key/value pairs, which are sometimes called items. Keys are strings. Any string (including the empty string) is a valid key. Values can be any data type supported by the structured clone algorithm."_ Note the last sentence. A discussion of the  changes in the specification might be able to be found by reading the mailing lists in the periods between the different draft publications.

Comment: @guest271314 - yes, that is interesting

Comment: @JaromandaX At one point `FileList` and `Blob`  objects were also monkey patched for use within the structured clone algorithm [2.9.8 Monkey patch for Blob and FileList objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#monkey-patch-for-blob-and-filelist-objects), though no longer possible, that am aware of, to post a `Blob` at `postMessage()` second parameter; an exception is thrown. Why the moves to and from the structured clone algorithm would be the next portion of inquiry.

Comment: Data needs to be serialized before they can be stored. Turning them to strings is just one method of serialization. You can also use other methods such as [JSON](http://json.org) or [pickles](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pickle-js/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, a lot of it is because of it is because of the way that it is was spec'd. Values at one time were discussed as being any data-type the is supported by the [structured clone algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data). However, due to browser compatibility issues (especially given the period of time when the spec was first initialized), support for returning a structured clone was just too much.

In general, if you actually need some form of key-value store, then you're going to want to move to the [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) side of things. Storage was really only intended for small pieces of information that didn't need to have any sort of transformation or manipulation done on them frequently.

I hope this clears things up a bit. :)